# JavaScript function that responds to user input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to write a javascript/angular js function to achieve the following: when a user enters a number, it will tell them if the number is too high or low (> 100 is too high)

here is my html code:

```
<div>
    <p id="num">Number : <input type="number"> </p>
    <p id="demo" onkeyup="numberToHigh()"> </p>
</div>
```

here is my js code:

```
function numberToHigh(){
var number = document.getElementById('num');
var message = document.getElementById('demo');
if (number > 100) {
    message.innerHTML = "number too high";
}else{
    message.innerHTML = "number ok";
}

}

});
```

I can't figure out why nothing is happening when i enter a value into the text area.

Comment: How did you link the script in the HTML file?

Comment: <script src="hello.js"></script> . like that. the html file is called hello.html and js is hello.js

Comment: Your document may be parsed after the JavaScript in some case, so you need to listen to the _DOMLoaded event_ first, which will wrap all your JavaScript code. Else, the function seems to be ready to work.

Comment: It is most probably the **Ready** Issue.. Please add your script on top of the page. And use Chrome/Firefox to Debug with console to see the issue

Comment: You function must be available before the click on the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting wrong element value in JS and also given the event lister to wrong element , should get the value from the input box and invoke the lister of input box

**Invoke it in *onchang*e** to work it in up and down arrow clicks

```
<script>
function numberToHigh(){
var number = document.getElementById('num').value;
var message = document.getElementById('demo');
if (number > 100) {
    message.innerHTML = "number too high";
}else{
    message.innerHTML = "number ok";
}

}
</script>

<div>
    <p >Number : <input id="num" onchange="numberToHigh()" onkeyup="numberToHigh()" type="number"> </p>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should attach event listener to `input` element and not to your `p` element.

Comment: Please see that the op is trying to do the operation on the keyup of the element (p) which is just fine

Comment: keyup on an empty (p)?

Comment: @Akshay Khandelwal how do you type in an p without designmode?

Comment: He/She may have a css bound to the <p> which makes it look like a button. Have we even extracted that information from him/her

Comment: And you can have the element focussable for keyup to work on any type of element

Answer (score 2):

`var num` is selecting the wrong element (it should be the `input`). You also need the `value` of this element rather that the element itself. You are also binding the `keyup` event to the wrong element (this should also be the `input`)...

```js
function numberToHigh(){
    var number = document.getElementById('num').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('demo');
    console.log(number)
    if (number > 100) {
        message.innerHTML = "number too high";
    }else{
        message.innerHTML = "number ok";
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Number : <input id="num" type="number" onchange="numberToHigh()" onkeyup="numberToHigh()"> </p>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
</div>
```

EDIT

You may want to also call your function when the `onchange` event fires to capture the +/- button clicks of the number input

Comment: Snippet works when typing with the keyboard the value, doesn't when using input number arrow to increase/decrease the value.

Comment: Added `onchange` binding to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="number" id="num" onkeyup="numberToHigh()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You made many mistakes. I tried to correct them. You can use these :

```
<div>
    <p id="num">Number : <input id="numValue" type="number" /> </p>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
</div>



$("#numValue").keyup(function() {
    var number = document.getElementById('numValue').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('demo');
    if (number > 100) {
        message.innerHTML = "number too high";
    }else{
        message.innerHTML = "number ok";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement function on ng-change of input, this is pure angular code

```
     <div>
        <p id="num">Number : <input type="number" ng-model="number" ng-change="numberToHigh()"> </p>
/div>
```

Your **controller** looks like

```
   $scope.numberToHigh = function (){
      if ($scope.number > 100) {
             // do your work    
        }
       else{
        // do your work
        }    
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach event listener to input, try this

```js
function numberToHigh(){
  var number = document.getElementById('input_number');
  var message = document.getElementById('demo');
  if (number.valueAsNumber > 100) {
    message.innerHTML = "number too high";
  } else{
    message.innerHTML = "number ok";
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
    <p id="num">Number : <input id="input_number" onmousedown="numberToHigh()" onkeyup="numberToHigh()" type="number"> </p>
    <p id="demo" > </p>
</div>
```